# Make a grouping and transforming query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a test table:
**category**   **type**  **quantities**
 a      1    100
 a      2    150
 b      2    45
 b      3    68
 b      1    72
 c      2    90
 c      3    39

It is assume that only 3 types appeared. My goal is select out there categories, and quantities of each type. Result should like:

**category**   **type1**   **type2**   **type3**
 a      100    150    0
 b      72     45    68
 c      0     90    39

I'm trying with union, but I think it is redundant and not briefness:

```sql
select category, sum(type1)type1, sum(type2)type2 ,sum(type3) type3 from 
(
select category, sum(quantities) type1, 0 type2, 0 type3  from test where type=1 group by category
union all
select category, 0 type1, sum(quantities) type2, 0 type3  from test where type=2 group by category
union all
select category, 0 type1, 0 type2, sum(quantities) type3 from test where type=3 group by category
) group by category;
```

What can I do to shorten my query? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  category,
  nvl(sum(case when type = 1 then quantities end), 0) as type1,
  nvl(sum(case when type = 2 then quantities end), 0) as type2,
  nvl(sum(case when type = 3 then quantities end), 0) as type3
from mytable
group by category
order by category;
```

Comment: Why I made it too complicated? So clearly and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also known as a pivot table -- see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Thanks for useful documentation.